# How to add discounts for unsold products in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I have more than 1000 products, but many products are unsold. So for promotion, I need to add discount for those unsold products.

In promotions we can add Product discount and Shopping cart rule. But for unsold products there are no options to add discount.

How to add it from admin panel?

Comment: There is no default option for what you are checking for.

Comment: Then any modules are available?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/unsold-product-extension.html) extension to get unsold products and add the unsold(programmatically) products to specific category.

Then you can apply Catalog Price Rule for that specific category.

As i added, you can implement this in your custom module.